# filtrar por mes y año

Tags: sql-server, datatables, sql

hola a todos estoy creando una consulta para que me regrese por mes cierta información filtrando por mes y año, en el año tengo una variable @YEAR pero si uso la variable no me filtra y cuando quito la variable y la sustituyo por el año con numero si me filtra.

este el mi consulta

estoy usando SQL server

```html
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS',
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM', 
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND  A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS',
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM', 
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS',
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM', 
    
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND YEAR(A.Due_Date) = @YEAR AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM',


FROM Maintenance_v_Work_Request_e A
```

Comment: Para valorarlo, que tipo de valor es @YEAR, y si haces al inicio `DECLARE @YEAR int = 2019;` y ejecutas, no funciona?

Comment: Pon la definición de la variable, ahí puede estar el error. También sería interesante ver la opción de limitar resultados en el `WHERE` en vez de en los `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tu variable sea de tipo INT y que su valor sea distinto de NULL, ya que yo realice una prueba y si me funciona correctamente.

```
    DECLARE @year int 

    SET @year = 2019

    SELECT *
    FROM TABLA
    WHERE YEAR(Fecha) = @year --2019
```

Comment: Este es un anti-patrón de SQL que impide utilizar índices. Es recomendable no usar funciones sobre columnas en la clausula `WHERE`.